# How do I change the second dropdown based on value changes from first dropdown using a4j?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I am using 2 dropdowns in JSF. Need to use a4j RichFaces ajax call only. Based on value change in 1st dropdown, I Have to change display 2nd dropdown.

First dropdown having values: DC, RC and AB. 
In my 2nd Dropdpwn:

If value in Dropdown 1 is DC, change the value in selectItem to Dc related subjects. ( I have built list of subjects for DC)

Similarly if value in dropddown 2 is RC, change the value in selectItem to Dc related subjects. ( I have built list of subjects for DC)

If not Dc or RC, show the dropdpwn with null values.

Dropdown 1:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="skillSetArea"
                 valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changeskillSet}"
                 value="#{myBean.skillSet}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{referenceBean.skillSetCodes}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Dropdown 2:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="subjects"
                 value="#{demoBean.subjectCode}"
                 disabled="#{demoBean.showSubject}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{demoBean.showSubejctforDC}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Please add that to the question and format it correctly. Don't put it as a comment.

Comment: Have you tried looking around for examples using fairly straightforward search keywords "h:selectOneMenu a4j:support"? I found quite some examples.

Comment: Wrap _subjects_ with `<h:panelGroup id="parentOfSubjects">` and add `reRender` attribute in `a4j:support`for re-rendering parent of _subjects_: `<a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="parentOfSubjects"  />`